# Visual Studio 2015/17 Indentation Lines Color

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I have spent a long time trying to find out how to change the indent guidelines for visual studio, as the bright gray is really too distracting. I managed to change +/- collapse line, but not the indentation colors.

These are what I am talking about:
[image: Visual Studio Indent Lines]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are part of the [Productivity Power Tools 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/11/28/productivity-in-visual-studio-2017-rc/).  This is what they have on their docs:

> If you prefer not to see the lines, you can easily turn them off in Tools-Options-Text Editor-General-“Show structure guide lines”. You can also alter their color via the Text Editor “Block Structure Adornments” display item in Fonts and Colors.

But it seems to be outdated.  The color setting is now called **Structure Guidelines**